# ANTLR4 Building in Visual Studio 2017 (C++)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, antlr4

I'm trying to build ANTLR4 in Visual Studio (C++).

These are the errors:
[Error trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BXFp.png)

The unresolved externals are virtual destructors.

Why it is implemented like that? Pure virtual destructors must have a function body. How can I fix it and build ANTLR4?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For some reason the cpp files that define the destructors have to be added to the project by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you used the latest code from Github. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/1935) with fixes for the recent changes in the C++ target. Just download and apply this patch to make the code compiling. Currently there is no VS 2017 solution in the repo, so if you like you can create a pull request for that.

Comment: Your pull request made most of the warnings disappear (VS 2017). Thank you!!! Only one remains. Drastic change.
Warning C4996 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although not related to destructors, there are other challenges if you haven't overcome them already.  Getting ANTLR4 solutions to build in VS was a challenge.  Other than several nuget installs, I remember having to do some manipulations to the *project file* as in:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Antlr4 Include="YOURGRAMMAR.g4">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <Listener>True</Listener>
      <Visitor>True</Visitor>
    </Antlr4>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.5.3 YOUR VERSION" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And after all that I still don't have syntax highlighting in the .g4 grammar files.  But the change above at least set up the build actions and let the background ANTLR classes rebuild when necessary.

Comment: In the end, I used Mike's pull request. Thanks!